# When we create a constructor in JAVA, is it overloaded or overridden?

Tags: java, constructor, overriding, overloading, parent-child

In Java,
Overloading is creating methods with the same name but different signature and Overriding is creating methods with the same name and the same signature.

So what happens, overloading or overriding, when we create a constructor in child class in JAVA?

Comment: Neither. You overload a constructor by writing multiple constructors in the same class, not in inherited classes. And constructors aren't subject to overriding. If I call `new X("Hi")`, I _know_ I'm calling a constructor defined and implemented in `X`, not a constructor overridden in some subclass of `X`.

Answer (score 4):

Neither. Constructors are different from methods. You overload a constructor by writing multiple constructors in the same class, not in inherited classes. And constructors aren't subject to overriding. If I call `new X("Hi")`, I *know* I'm calling a constructor defined and implemented in `X`, not a constructor overridden in some subclass of `X`, or inherited from some superclass of `X`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/) [§8.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8),

> Constructor declarations are not members. They are **never inherited** and therefore are **not subject to hiding or overriding.**

So it's not overriding. And since constructors are not inherited, it's not overloading the constructor in the super either, when you declare a constructor in the subclass. It is however:

- overloading other constructors declared in the same class, if any, or;
- replacing the default constructors if no constructors have been declared before.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah. Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

A class consists of members (fields or methods) and constructors - as entirely different things. But you want to do a conceptual comparison.

```
class A {
    A() { }
}

class B extends A {
    B() {
        System.out.println("Bar");
    }
}
```

Internally in the JVM (java virtual machine) the constructor signatures are `A.<init>()`

And `B()` is implemented internally as:

```
int field1;
String field2;
String field3 = null;
int field4 = 42;

B() {
    // 1. Explicit or implicit super constructor:
    super(); // A.<init>();

    // 2. All fields with initialisation:
    field3 = null;
    field4 = 42;

    // 3. The remaining code:
    System.out.println("Bar");
}
```

This looks like overriding `A.<init>()` (though `@Override` is not allowed), but the base method is called implicitly (parameterless), or explicitly as `super(...)`.

Overloading means having more than 1 constructor in B.